# Is there any legitimate reason to PUSH a target address to the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, call, callstack

So that, the pushed/new target address is used in place of the original return address?

Comment: define legitimate.

Comment: @MikeNakis Legitimate = Something that is not an attack. e.g. overflow attacks modify the return address.

Comment: It shows up in various places for various reasons. One example is in Microsoft MBR sectors where you see something like `push 0` `push label` `retf` `label:` after it relocates itself. This is because MASM makes it hard to code the more direct far jump instruction (`jmp 0:label`).

Comment: This can be used in self-modifying code or in procs with multiple exit points. For example, I used this approach somewhen in a timer interrupt handler. Interrupt handler checks how many ticks left and if it's greater than 0, then resume normal program execution. Otherwise redirect execution flow to cleanup-and-shutdown code

Comment: overflow attacks modify the return address by causing it to be overwritten by something, not by executing a PUSH instruction.

Comment: I overwrote the return address in an ARM emulator I wrote when switching between ARM and Thumb mode, which would be legitimate by your definition.